# Setup a switch at home which acts as an extension of my office over VPN with transparent bridging

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vpn

Basically, at home I have a system with 2 NICs.  1 is the my normal home network, and over this I will run vpnc to connect to my work PC (both run Linux).

What I want is that the second NIC on my home PC gets bridged to my work network at Layer 2.

I should be able to plug in a switch to my second NIC and anything else on this switch will be able to participate in things like DHCP, getting addresses from my work's network and generally access the company network as though they were plugged in locally.

How can I set this up? I have full control over both PCs and they run Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have a "bridged" VPN connection in the first place where Layer 2 (Ethernet) traffic is tunneled instead of IP. - I don't think this is supported with the configuration you aim at - VPN access solutions are usually set up at the IP level. There may be workarounds like [Proxy ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP) (which is what Microsoft RRAS is doing) so the VPN clients appear to be local to the network, but it is not quite the same - security and implementation details will get in the way of using it like a bridge.

As an open project, [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net) is capable of encapsulating Ethernet over an encrypted TCP or UDP connection.